# CakePHP form $options['options']

Tags: php, oop, forms, cakephp

Hey!  Total CakePHP noob here.

Updated at bottom /

This is sort of a two fold question.  In a view that is used for adding `user` objects I would like to use a drop down (selection) field in the form.

Each `user` belongs to a `group` so when I add a user I want a drop down that contains all of the groups that the user could possibly join.  Currently the `group_id` field is a textfield.  I know how to force it to be a selection field, but I don't know how to populate the selection with the names of the groups programmatically.

The Current method:

```
echo $form->input('group_id', array(
    '1' => 'NameOfGroup1',
    '2' => 'NameOfGroup2',
    '3' => 'NameOfGroup3')
    );
```

I want to generate the options array programmatically though.

```
echo $form->input('group_id', $this->Group->find('list'));
```

This doesn't work though.  I get an error:

```
Undefined property: View::$Group [APP/views/users/add.ctp, line 8]
```

To me this means that I don't have access to the `Group` object from inside my user view.

How can I accomplish this?  Again, I want to do it programmatically so that it updates as I add groups or remove them.

EDIT:  Why doesn't this work?

```
// In views/users/someaction.ctp
echo $form->input('group_id',
                  array('options' => $this->formOptionsGroups)
                  );

// In controllers/users_controller.php
function someaction() {
    // Any other logic
    $this->set('formOptionsGroups', $this->Group->find('list'));
}
```

Error is that Group is an undefined object.

Comment: Relevant tutorials: http://book.cakephp.org/view/335/Create-a-Posts-Controller and http://book.cakephp.org/view/336/Creating-Post-Views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not necessary to use the `requestAction` function in your situation.Because you can get the grouplist in your users controller easily then assign it to your user-add page where you need it.That would be more graceful.

BTW,[about requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/view/434/requestAction) from the cookbook: **requestAction is best used in conjunction with (cached) elements – as a way to fetch data for an element before rendering.**

**E.g**

```
/*code In the your user-add action of the users controller*/
function useradd()
{
    ......
    //your ownstuff skipped

    $grouplist = $this->User->Group->find('list');
    $this->set("grouplist",$grouplist);   
}
```

Then in your view of the useradd action :

```
echo $form->input('group_id', $grouplist);
```

Comment: Can you provide example code.  I didn't quite follow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with how I was requesting the action in the controller.

A correct implementation is:

```
echo $form->input('group_id', 
                  array('options' => $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'formSelectOptions')))
                  );
```

And then in the groups controller:

```
// formSelectOptions() returns array for use with a form $options['options']
function formSelectOptions() {
    return $this->Group->find('list');
}
```

Comment: Do it the other way around, find the data in the controller, then `set()` it to be available in the view. `requestAction` has quite a lot of overhead.